# InvalidCastException for LINQPAD

Tags: sqlite, linqpad

I'm using LinqPad and IQ driver for SQLite. I have connection with this file. Look:
[image]

*"Okreslone rzutowanie jest nieprawidlowe"* - it can be simple translate to *"invalid cast"*, but `Zbiors.Count()` return value **8**.
[image]
When i'm trying do it in SQL query:

```
select * from zbior
```

[image]

Then all's ok. How can i get same result by "C#", not by SQL query?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, the types are incorrect. SQLite has a horrible "feature" whereby you can put strings into integer columns and vice versa. The column types are merely suggestion and are not enforced. So what looks like integers in your data might actually be strings, causing in InvalidCastException when the IQ driver tries to read them.